# Why are "nation" and "national" pronounced differently?

Tags: pronunciation

I was wondering why *nation* is pronounced *nay-shun* and *national* is pronounced *nah-shu-nal*. My question relates to the difference between pronouncing "Nay" and "Nah". The spelling of "nation" in "national" is the same as "nation", but the "na" parts of the word are pronounced differently. Is there some kind of rule or pattern for this?

Comment: related: [UK emphasis on the second syllable vs US emphasis on the first](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7831/uk-emphasis-on-the-second-syllable-vs-us-emphasis-on-the-first)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There isn't a pattern or rule; *nation/national* is unique.  Of [all -ational words](http://www.onelook.com/?w=*ational&scwo=1&sswo=1&first=1), only *national* and *rational* are pronounced with /ˈæʃən/ (rhymes with "ashen").  *Ration/rational*, however, is usually consistently /'ræʃən/ and /'ræʃənl/ ([or /ˈreɪʃən/ and /ˈreɪʃənl/](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ration?s=t), though sometimes, as Peter Shor [points out](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62429/why-are-nation-and-national-pronounced-differently#comment119190_62451),  /ˈreɪʃən/ is paired with /'ræʃənl/, using the same respective pronunciations as *nation/national*), even though the two terms are not closely related in meaning.  *National* is therefore an oddball, being pronounced /ˈnæʃənl/ when *nation* is (as normal *-ation* words are) pronounced /ˈneɪʃən/.

I don't think anyone knows exactly why *national* isn't pronounced /ˈneɪʃənl/ like all the other *-ational* words.

Comment: I would disagree with the statement that *ration/rational* is consistent. I believe I hear both pronunciations of *ration* quite often (in the U.S. Northeast), but I don't think I've ever heard anybody pronounce [rational](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/rational?s=t) so it doesn't rhyme with *national*.

Comment: I've never heard /ˈreɪʃən/.  I'd just assumed that anyone who would say it would also say /ˈreɪʃənl/.  Well, I'll edit.

Comment: How do you pronounce "Newfoundland"?

Comment: I pronounce it /ˈnufənlənd/.

Comment: Let me take back my comment about hearing /ˈreɪʃən/ in the Northeast. I have certainly heard it in some regions of the USA, but I think it's usually /ˈræʃən/ here.

Comment: After some googling, here's my best guess: the East Coast and the South pronounce it /'ræʃən/, and California pronounces it /ˈreɪʃən/. For the rest of the country, I don't know.

Answer (score 4):

I would bet against the existence of any productive process in any form of modern English that accounts for the alternation between the vowel in the first syllables of "nation" and "national", though it seems Chomsky & Halle would disagree with me.  In any case, I believe this is probably just the result of a process of [trisyllabic laxing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trisyllabic_laxing) that occurred in earlier stages of English.

Comment: Note that the alternation is not that the _-ational_ [ˈæʃɨnəl] word is not the base form that the _-ation_ [ˈeɪʃɨn] pronunciation would be conditioned by, but the other way around.  So words like "ration", where there's an [æ] in the _-ation_ form, would not be expected to have [ˈeɪʃɨn] pronunciations just because they also happen to have a form with _-al_.