# Where in the U.S. do people change the stress of umbrella, adult and TV to the first syllable?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, dialects, stress

Is it just a small percentage of the population in that region who stress the first syllable, or is it widespread?

In other words, if I visit such a region will I find almost everyone talking like that or is it something restricted to a certain neighbourhood?

Comment: It's certainly *not* typical in this American's experience, though my mother (who is "of a certain age") says "TEE-vee" and it drives me *nuts*.

Comment: It's not clear if you're looking for a place where all three things happen or if you're looking for different places where any of them might happen.

Comment: @wfaulk all three examples in the same place.

Comment: [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/umbrella) says that accenting the first syllable for *umbrella* is "especially Southern". I would guess that for all of these words, the main place you'd find first-syllable stress is in the South. I certainly don't hear the first syllable stressed often for these in the Northeast.

Comment: @PeterShor "The South" is very large.

Comment: @Centaurus Maybe, but there's something we generally call a "southern accent". "The South" often refers to the mostly rural states in southeastern US, roughly from Missouri to Georgia.

Comment: @Barmar  I don't mean to be a prick but I've never read or heard anything about Missouri being a southern state.

Comment: @Centaurus I've only known one person from MO (in college 35 years ago), he seemed southern, and he had a twang, especially when he was on the phone with his family.

Comment: @Barmar I see, you don't mean the geographical South.

Comment: No, I'm talking about the cultural and linguistic South. Geographically, MO is on the border between South and Midwest.

Comment: @Centaurus: Missouri is a southern state because of the [Missouri compromise.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missouri_Compromise) It was first settled by people who talked Southern.

Comment: Adult is probably an exception.  I've interacted with people from all over the US, and 1st vs. 2nd syllable stress is very varied and widespread, not a Southern thing.  Sometimes people will say it one way one time and the other way another time for no obvious reason.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Shifting second-syllable stress to the first syllable is characteristic of Southern (US) accents. Indeed, it's a trope, reaching #59 on the Stuff Southern People Like blog:

> [How to Sound Southern: Accent the First Syllable](http://stuffsouthernpeoplelike.com/2011/01/19/59-accenting-the-first-syllable/) … HALLoween, THANKSgiving, TEEvee, UMbrella, and JUly

The *THANKSgiving* pronunciation is also covered in a [Language Log post](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/005147.html) which also mentions *ADult* and *UMbrella* among others.

The association is borne out by at least one famous study, the [Harvard Dialect Survey](http://www4.uwm.edu/FLL/linguistics/dialect/maps.html), started by Bert Vaux and Scott Golder in 2002. [Joshua Katz](http://www4.ncsu.edu/~jakatz2/), a Ph.D. student in statistics at North Carolina State University, created a series of maps using that data that made the rounds on social media last year thanks to the *New York Times*. Those pronunciations all sound unusual to me, but that's because I'm SoCal through and through— in fact, [not just SoCal, but downright OC](http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2013/12/20/sunday-review/dialect-quiz-map.html?r=0022208k000082200jj020400100j10j840j02002002020010).

Question 48 of the survey addresses *umbrella*, and while stress on the second syllable predominates throughout the U.S. (76%), the distribution of *UMbrella* is clearer when looking at the full results:

[image: UMbrella occurs in the South, Appalachia, and parts of the Upper Midwest]

The survey also attests to *[INsurance](http://www4.uwm.edu/FLL/linguistics/dialect/staticmaps/q_45.html)* and *[THANKsgiving](http://www4.uwm.edu/FLL/linguistics/dialect/staticmaps/q_47.html)*. It is seems strange, however, that not even Dixie can agree on how to pronounce the quintessentially Southern *[pecan](http://spark.rstudio.com/jkatz/Data/comp-21.png)*.

According to Macmillan, stressing the first syllable of *adult* is characteristically [British](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/adult) whereas stressing the second is [American](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/adult), although I do hear the first-syllable stress commonly in the U.S. as well. As with the Southerners, however, this too [seems to be word-specific](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7831). The dictionaries draw no such distinction for *[TV](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/pronunciation/british/tv)*.

Comment: Very interesting data maps, choster. I come from a hotbed of pi-KAHN (southeast Texas) and I can vouch for the accuracy of the map for that region and that word. In the case of _Thanksgiving_, it seems to me that the most natural way to say the word when I was growing up was as if it were two words—THANKS GIVing—which may be one of the "Other" options listed for that word. Anyway, thanks for the fascinating information.

Comment: Great answer! Encyclopedic! I wonder why there's a lost belt in the Wisconsin/Minnesota border.

Comment: I can verify that people in Georgia accent damn near everything on the first syllable. Not just UM-brella and IN-surance, but words like WITH-draw, RE-port, IN-deed, RE-turn, IN-clude, and UN-less.

Comment: I *think* that I change the stress in "adult" depending on part of speech—it's always the second syllable for the noun (and verb), but often first syllable for the adjective. It's possible that distinction is more in my head than my mouth, though.

Answer (score 1):

I am from Texas and it is not uncommon to hear the first syllable given emphasis. However, I often hear the emphasis switched to the second syllable if the tone of the conversation turns sarcastic or commanding. I would be cautious of a woman puts the emphasis on the second syllable of in-deed. That is a pretty good indicator that fur is about to fly. I'd back up or vacate the area. Just sayin'..

Answer (score -2):

I've lived in Minneapolis/St Paul, Madison, WI, and Long Island, NY.. I can say that I have never heard "insurance" pronounced with the accent on the first syllable until I moved to Indpls, IN.. They will frequently pronounce "wash" as "warsh" too.  I just attributed it to the poor school system here and small percentage of college educated residents as I know that Indpls is not considered part of the south.

Comment: I'm not sure that stressing the first syllable of "insurance" is a pronunciation feature that would tend to occur as the result of poor schooling, or that would be expected to be eliminated in individuals with college educations. There might be some correlation, but I would expect regional effects to be stronger.