# Is there any case when it's correct to pronounce the word "police" with the stress on the first syllable?

Tags: pronunciation, stress

Is there any case when it's correct to pronounce the word *police* with the stress on the first syllable: 
 /ˈpəlis/?

Comment: Of possible interest: *[Where in the U.S. do people change the stress of umbrella, adult and TV to the first syllable?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/208057)*

Comment: I spent my teens in Glasgow, Scotland and the slang for police was 'polis' with the emphasis on the first syllable. I have no idea where this comes from unless it is from the French.

Comment: @NigelJ I also think of it as typically Glaswegian/Scottish (just from watching TV!)

Comment: @JamesRandom It used to be safer to watch Glasgow on telly than to live there. I think things may have changed since the 60s.

Comment: When you're talking to your friends in the 'hood.

Comment: @HotLicks  friends would be homies.   Talking is conversating

Comment: Yes, in Germany because then you're making fun of them  :)

Comment: The way this question is phrased is bizarre. Correct *according to who?* There is no single authority that defines what's "correct" in English. "Correct" is based on usage.

Comment: @only_pro - It's only correct if it's "to whom".

Answer (score 15):

It is possible to put the main stress on the first syllable of *police* in some varieties of English. When the first syllable of *police* is stressed, the vowel is not a schwa. It is the "goat" vowel or "long o" sound: /ˈpolis/ or /ˈpoʊlis/ (both of these phonemic transcriptions are identical).

There is no way to classify this pronunciation as indisputably "correct" or "incorrect" in a global sense, because there is no consensus about how to define "correct pronunciation". That said, Mark Liberman (in the post linked below) suggests that "the initially-stressed [pronunciation of *police*] seems to have become stigmatized, and have been abandoned by many better-educated or more upwardly-mobile people." There are many specific speakers who would never stress the first syllable of *police* in any context. So it's acceptable for a non-native speaker to always say /pəˈlis/, with stress only on the second syllable.

The pronunciation /ˈpolis/, with stress on the first syllable, is supposed to occur for some speakers in the Southern US, according to the following sources:

- Straight Dope Message Board discussion: [Poh-lice, or police?](https://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/archive/index.php/t-502029.html)
- "[The Southern Stress on the First Syllable in Words like Cement and Police](https://www.waywordradio.org/southern-first-syllable-stress-on-cement-police/)",  by Grant Barrett, *A Way with Words*
- "[Thanksgiving Variation](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/005147.html)", Mark Liberman, *Language Log*

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer.

Comment: Does this mean the [iː] gets shortened in the process does its quality change? I am quite confused what is called by "stress" here.

Comment: @VladimirF: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_(linguistics). In many cases unstressed vowels are somewhat shorter or have somewhat different quality, but the term "stress" does not refer to either of those facts, and in the specific case of *police* I don't think the length and quality of the /i/ are noticeably different between the two pronunciations. (Disclaimer: I come from a region where only the second-syllable-stressed pronunciation is found.)

Comment: I can imagine an SSBE speaker giving a version of *police* with a stress on each syllable for emphatic effect: "Dont mess with him. He's a member of the POH LEESE, don't you know"

Comment: I think the stigmatization Liberman is talking about is that this is associated with rednecks, hillbillies, and other categories that are stereotypically uneducated.

Comment: @VladimirF: Phonetic vowel length in English depends on a variety of factors, so I'm not using length markers in my transcriptions here. The quality of /i/ in my accent is (broadly) [i], whether stressed or unstressed. See "[The Undesirability of length marks in EFL phonemic transcription](http://www.yek.me.uk/undesire.html)", (1975),  by Jack Windsor Lewis.